# Command Prompt: Error Unable to access jarfile selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, command-prompt

I'm trying to run from Command Prompt the selenium server but this error shows up when I write java

Command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
```

Error:

```
Error Unable to access jarfile selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

To start the `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar` from the *Command Prompt* you can use the following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
```

Console Output:

```
$>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
00:26:20.250 INFO [GridLauncherV3.parse] - Selenium server version: 3.141.59, revision: e82be7d358
00:26:20.750 INFO [GridLauncherV3.lambda$buildLaunchers$3] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2020-12-13 00:26:21.093:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2998ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
00:26:22.703 INFO [WebDriverServlet.<init>] - Initialising WebDriverServlet
00:26:25.993 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
```

Comment: that's what I'm typing and the error shows up

Comment: @AggelosM Definitely you missed `java` as per your [initial version of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65268343/1).

Comment: i added the file location to ```PATH``` and I can still only run it from the file location on my pc. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the absolute path to the jar file. E.g. C:\Directory-where-the-file-is\selenium-server-standalone-version.jar

Comment: the command will be java -jar "C:\Directory-where-the-file-is\selenium-server-standalone-version.jar"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download Selenium grid from https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/
where the selenium-server-{version}.jar will be downloaded and in the folder where this .jar file is located, cmd should be opened and can be launched with the command:
**java -jar selenium-server-{version}.jar**
Then it will be launched.
Just make sure whether you downloaded folder containing selenium jar files or **selenium server grid [ server's jar file which is actually the server]** is downloaded.